# Selecting only the first cell in a range that meets the condition

Tags: excel, vba

My code copies a text from a cell in Matrix 1 to all the cells that meet my criteria in Matrix 2. But I want it to copy it only to the first cell that meets my critiria in Matrix 2 and then stop.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer

For j = 2 To 2
    For i = 21 To 21

        If Cells(i, j).Value > 0 Then
            Cells(i, j).Value = Cells(i, j).Value - 1
            Cells(i, j).Offset(0, -1).Select
        End If

        'as it says - for EACH - so it copies in aLL the cells'
        'I can't Change the range though, cause there will come a Loop eventually'
        For Each cell In Range("a1:aap15")

            If cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 6 Then
                If cell.Value = "" Then
                    cell.Value = ActiveCell.Value
                End If
            End If
        Next
    Next
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: why do you have the second loop ? `For i = 21 To 21` ? what's the purpose ?(or the first one ? )

Comment: I will reduce the value of b21 until it's 0, then I will continue with b22 and so on. I just didn't come to the part yet, so I neglected that complication and made it easier until I have figured out the proplems I already have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `Exit For` command to exit a for loop. It looks like you want to add it here:

```
If cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 6 Then
    If cell.Value = "" Then
        cell.Value = ActiveCell.Value
        Exit For
    End If
End If
```

Note: not tested. Let me know if you have any problems

Comment: I just realised that Excel searches within the range from left to right - then top to bottom. Can I make it search the first column from top to bottom and the second and so on? Should I open a new question for this?

Comment: I'd check to see if the question already exists and has already been answered on here, or if you can find out with a Google search. If that fails then it's worth asking in a new question

Comment: Okay, I wll. Thanks

Comment: Actually the answer is simple enough for me to add in a comment: change your `For Each cell In Range("a1:aap15")` to `For Each cell In Range("a1:aap15").Columns`. This will loop through each column from top to bottom, then left to right

Comment: Actually, it doesn't Show an error message, but it also doesn't copy the text anymore. hmmmm

Comment: Sorry - that's bad advice. There's a bit more to it - I'd start a new question

Comment: I see. That's okay. I will, then.